# Why does plotly's colorbar cover a range other than the one I specified

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, plotly-python

I'm starting to use plotly within a Jupyter Notebook, and have noticed that I do not always get the range of tick values that I specify. For example in the following code, I specify a colorbar range of 0.5 - 3.5

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.offline as off
import pandas as pd

def map_test(begin="2000", end="2020"):

    # Get time range start/stop
    begin = pd.to_datetime(begin).tz_localize('UTC')
    end = pd.to_datetime(end).tz_localize('UTC')
    begin_str = begin.strftime("%b-%d-%Y")
    end_str = end.strftime("%b-%d-%Y")
    
    # Dummy Data Points
    lat_min = 47.763135
    lat_max = 54.258862
    lat_ser = pd.Series({0:48.316640, 1:49.085321, 2:48.2})
    
    lon_min = -130.431343
    lon_max = -123.0
    lon_ser = pd.Series({0:-130.050292, 1:-123.329648, 2:-122.9})
    
    log_depth_ser = pd.Series({0:2.992288, 1:2.0, 2:2.5})


    # Using dbl. negatives to trick plotly's colorbar into 
    # having larger numbers, indicative of greater depth,
    # at bottom of colorbar
    tickvals = np.arange(-0.5,-3.5,-0.1) #!!!!!!!! Key Line Giving Colorbar Value Range !!!!
    ticktext = [str(f"{-1*val:.1f}") for val in tickvals]


    # Dicts used to define data
    colorbar_dict = {'x': 0.75,
                     'title':  'Log\u2081\u2080 (Depth\u2098)',
                     'thickness': 10,
                     'titleside': "right",
                     'outlinecolor': "rgba(68, 68, 68, 0)",
                     'ticks': "outside",
                     'tickvals': tickvals,
                     'ticktext': ticktext,
                     'ticklen': 3,
                     'showticksuffix': "last",
                     'ticksuffix': " log(meters, 10)",
                     'dtick': .1}

    marker_dict = {'color': -1*log_depth_ser, #negative used to sync w/colorbar
                   'size': 6,
                   'colorscale': 'deep',
                   'reversescale': True,
                   'colorbar': colorbar_dict}

    data_dict1 = {'type': 'scattergeo',
                  'lat': lat_ser,
                  'lon': lon_ser,
                  'marker': marker_dict,
                  'mode': 'markers'
                  }

    # Dicts used to define layout
    #  Title Dict
    title_dict = {'text': f"ONC Sonar Sensors<br>From {begin_str} to {end_str}",
                  'y':0.9,
                  'x':0.5,
                  'xanchor': 'center',
                  'yanchor': 'top'}

    #  Dicts for Geo Layout
    proj_dict = {'type': 'robinson',
                 'rotation': {'lon': -100}}

    lonaxis_dict = {'showgrid': True,
                    'gridwidth': 0.5,
                    'range': [ lon_min-.4, lon_max+.4 ],
                    'dtick': 5}

    lataxis_dict = {'showgrid': True,
                    'gridwidth': 0.5,
                    'range': [ lat_min-.4, lat_max+.4 ],
                    'dtick': 5}

    geo_dict = {'showframe': True,
                'framewidth': 25,
                'scope': 'north america',
                'showland': True,
                'landcolor': "rgb(212, 212, 212)",
                'showocean': True,
                'oceancolor': "rgb(180, 180, 225)",
                'subunitcolor': "rgb(0,0,0)",
                'resolution': 50,
                'projection': proj_dict,
                'lonaxis': lonaxis_dict,
                'lataxis': lataxis_dict}

    # Layout Dict
    layout_dict = {'title': title_dict,
                   'geo': geo_dict,
                   'showlegend': False}                

    # Dicts defining figure
    fig = {'data':[data_dict1], 
           'layout':layout_dict}


    off.iplot(fig)
    return
```

However, the colorbar I get has a different range of values:

[image: Resulting Plotly Image]

Is there some way to `force` plotly to use the range I specify? Or must I live with plotly's adjustments to what I specified?